# I want to move this text just a little bit more

Tags: html

Currently I got this code:

```
<p>
align="left"><strong>Ver. 0.1.0 - Current features
<p>
<p>
```

I want to move the text just a little bit more. How can I do this? What code do I need to add?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `span` to call the class which you could style in your CSS.

```css
.modify {
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="modify">Ver. 0.1.0 - Current features</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS.

use **padding** or **margin** as your convenient.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="margin-left: 12px;font-weight:bold">Ver. 0.1.0 - Current features</p>
```

You can also use padding to move the text. Just replace "margin" with "padding" and change pixel value according to your need

Comment: I tried this, but it's like my code blocks it. I can only move it a bit, then no longer. It's like the page not is width enough.